# Android popup menu on left click

Tags: android, menu, popup

hey guys i try to get A popup menu when i click left click on the device i don't want open
popup menu by using button just want open when i click the left.

Like this :

http://ecee.colorado.edu/ecen3000/labs/lab8/files/javaLab1_files/image020.jpg

Thanks all...................

i tried

```
  public void showMenu(View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);

            // This activity implements OnMenuItemClickListener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener((OnMenuItemClickListener) this);
            popup.inflate(R.menu.actions);
            popup.show();
        }


        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is a "left click"?

Comment: Do you mean like tap? Your question does not make sense?

Comment: I think you want to say. The button on the left of the device? The Meny Button? if so check Option Menu at this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: i saw this but i didn't know how

Comment: Do you mean the back button?

Answer (score 0):

By touching left side of the screen you need to popup. My suggestion is first you have to add setOnTouchListener for the root layout you created in xml.

and by using the below override method u can get the touch event of x and y position where the 
finger is placed on the screen, then restrict the range to corner as you need and compare the touch x and y, if it is between the range then popup your diaglog.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
int x = (int)event.getX();
int y = (int)event.getY();
int action = event.getAction();
if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
//finger placed down, this will run
}
else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
 //finger is up, this will run
}
else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
//finger is moved, this will run
```

For clear understanding check this link (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html)

Comment: this is hard there is no other way ?